# Two level async-await call

Tags: c#, async-await

Recently I ran into some asynchronous code with async-await. My question is what is the difference between two code blocks below -

**Code block - 1**

```
public async Task Method1(string fileName)
{
    await Method2(fileName);
}

public async Task Method2(string filePath)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>{
         //do some task
    });
}
```

**Code block - 2**

```
public async Task Method1(string fileName)
{
    await Method2(fileName);
}

public async Task Method2(string filePath)
{
    Task.Run(() =>{
         //do some task
    });
}
```

The difference among these two codes is await on Method2. What happens when a third method(say Method3) calls Method1? What are the differences in execution observed from Method3?

Comment: Code #2 should give you a warning explaining exactly what the difference is. Don't ignore warnings from the compiler.

Comment: @svick Thanks. The compiler says that the method lacks a await operator and will run synchronously. Now, think of the method3 that I mentioned. When method3 calls method1, control is returned to method3 after reaching the await call in both cases. So, what's the difference?

Comment: The difference is when the `Task` returned from `Method1` completes. With #2, it will complete immediately (not waiting for the `Task` started in `Task.Run()` to complete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a serious problem with `Method2`:

```
public async Task Method2(string filePath)
{
    Task.Run(() =>{
         //do some task
    });
}
```

It runs synchronously and returns a `Task` object which is complete (`Task.IsComplete == true`). Before it returns though, it starts another task (with `Task.Run`), which runs asynchronously and which completion status result gets lost ("fire and forget"). It would make more sense to put it this way:

```
public Task Method2(string filePath)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>{
         //do some task
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second code block, Method2 will complete without waiting for the Task.Run within Method2 to be completed.

It depends on what you need in terms of implementation. If you want to initialize a variable in Method2 for example and the callee expects this variable to be initialized, the 2nd code block will cause unexpected errors.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand clearly. can you explain in detail?

Comment: In code block 2, Method2 runs a task. Lets say this tasks takes 10seconds to complete.
Method2 will actually finalize before the task finishes. Meaning you can run Method2 without waiting 10seconds for completion and do something else in the meantime... drink coffee or what not

Comment: no in code block one, the await statement in front of your Task is the instruction to wait for the task to complete whatever it does before the rest of the code of method 2 can be excecuted.

Comment: Think of method1. In both cases the control is immediately returned to method1 as there is nothing done after Task.Run().

Comment: your example is pseudo code, just imagine both Tasks are implementing something very complex which takes 10seconds.
In your first example, the Method2 would take 10seconds to complete because the task takes this long...
In the second example, Method2 will return immediately because it does not wait for the task to complete...